# Javascript function that takes a function OR any parameter to be evaluated by that function

Tags: javascript

I was asked today to create a function `validate` so that I can use it was such:

```
validate(input => input > 2);
validate(5) // return true
validate(input => input ** 2);
validate(5) // return 25
```

I have thought about this and I can only think of a common pattern instantiating the function with another validator function like so:

```
const validate = (input => input)(input => input > 2);
validate(5) // returns true
```

However, this did not accomplish the requirement since I cannot pass another validator function after I have already defined it in the constructor.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Removing the functional programming tag because this question is not about FP. In fact, the problem described breaks the basic tenets of FP, i.e. purity and referential transparency.

Comment: This question is part of an interview question. I think it is meant to prompt a discussion on FP.

Comment: Well, if that was an interview question then you don't need that job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prototypes.

```
let validate = function(x){
  if(typeof(x)=="function"){
    validate.prototype.func = x;
  }else if(validate.prototype.func){
    return validate.prototype.func(x);
  }
}

validate(3) // return undefined
validate(x => x > 2)
validate(3) // return true
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a name for this type of programming? I haven't seen this used anywhere. What's a typical example usage from this?

Comment: @qvn This is a gross abuse of prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer? We first use an IIFE to create scope to store our `validator` function. If we determine the `validator` doesn't exist yet, we store the provided function as the validator. Next time we see the validator exists, so we pass it the number.

Note that this isn't *super* safe as you might want to verify the first argument passed to the `validate` function is indeed a function. If it isn't you'll probably want to throw an error or something like that.

```js
const validate = (function() {
  let validator;
  return function(arg) {
    if (typeof validator !== "function") {
      validator = arg;
    } else {
      const result = validator(arg)
      validator = undefined;
      return result;
    }
  }
})();

validate(input => input > 2);
console.log(validate(5)) // return true
validate(input => input ** 2);
console.log(validate(5)) // return 25
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Good use of Closures. In any case, code like that is a great exercise, but I would not recommend it in real life: quite confusing to the reader.

Comment: Yes, definitely super confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

```js
let validator = input => input;

const validate = value => {
    if (typeof value === "function") validator = value;
    else return validator(value);
};

console.log(validate(5)); // return 5
console.log(validate(5)); // return 5

validate(input => input > 2);
console.log(validate(5)); // return true
console.log(validate(5)); // return true

validate(input => input ** 2);
console.log(validate(5)); // return 25
console.log(validate(5)); // return 25
```

Note, that I made a few assumptions.

1. The initial value of the `validator` is the identity function. Hence, you can call `validate` with non-functional values before calling it with a functional value.
2. The `validator` is preserved in between function calls to `validate` with non-functional values.

Finally, I'd like to stress that please do not write code like this. A function should only do one thing, but this function does one of two things depending upon its input. It's unnecessarily complicated and it breaks the basic tenets of [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming), i.e. purity and referential transparency.

Whoever asked you this question, do not take programming advice from them.

Comment: Interesting. I should have thought of this solution quickly. I was asked this question as part of a senior engineer position and the interviewer is probably looking to test my understanding.

Comment: If that's the quality of interview questions then I would recommend finding a better job.